# Sencha Formfields passing empty fields

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm learning Sencha Touch. I created this app with a form before and it worked fine.

Now i'm working on a new little test app i copy the code from the other app and it only passes empty variables to the webservice.

the View:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
    Ext.define('Gasoline.view.InsertTankTrip', {
requires: [
    'Ext.form.FieldSet'
],

extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
xtype: 'inserttankpanel',
id: 'insertTankForm',

config: {
    title: 'Insert Tank Trip',
    iconCls: 'add',
    url: 'contact.php',
    items:[
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Insert Tank Trip',
            instructions: '(Make sure the info is correct!)',


            items:[
                {
                    xtype: 'datepickerfield',
                    label: 'Date',
                    name: 'date',
                    value: new Date()
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    label: 'Amount',
                    name: 'amount',
                    minValue:-9007199254740992,
                    maxValue: 9007199254740992
                }
            ]
        },{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Send',
            ui: 'confirm',
            action: 'insertTankSubmit'

        }
    ]
}
});
```

And in the controller :

```
launch: function() {
    // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
    Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

    // Initialize the main view
    Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('Gasoline.view.Main'));

    this.control({
        'button[action=insertTankSubmit]' : {
            tap: 'insertTankForm'
        }/*,
        'list[itemId=kingsLeagueList]' : {
            itemtap: 'onListTap'
        },
        'list[itemId=tournamentsList]' : {
            disclose: 'showDetail'
        }*/

    });
},

insertTankForm : function(){
console.log('test');
    var form = this.getInsertTankForm();

    form.submit({
        url:'contact.php'
    });
},
```

This sends the following to the webservice (which currently doesn't exist i just check with developer tools)

date:2012-07-26T17:02:16
amount:

so the date does get sent , the number doesnt

If i fill in a standard value for the number ... that gets sent but if you type something in , it still doesn't send that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried numerous solutions...none of them worked.

Lastly i deleted everything ... coded everything the exact same way and it started working ...

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
xtype: 'numberfield'
```

instead of

```
xtype: 'textfield'
```